# dynamically generate sql insert statements from results of a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to generate a series of insert statements based on the results of a query for a db2 and oracle databases.  In practice from a query like this

```
select g.id from SUV_OWNER.gruppi g 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SUV_OWNER.GRUPPIRUOLIPROCEDURE grp WHERE grp.gruppoid=g.gruppoid 
AND GRP.RUOLOID = 50)
AND 
G.CHIAVE LIKE 'ANA%';
```

which generates as output a sequence of numbers not known in advance as

```
30000  
30001  
.....
```

I have to generate for each number an insert statement as

```
insert into SUV_OWNER.GRUPPIRUOLIPROCEDURE (GRUPPOID, RUOLOID, PROCEDURAID) values  (30000, 141, 7);  
insert into SUV_OWNER.GRUPPIRUOLIPROCEDURE (GRUPPOID, RUOLOID, PROCEDURAID) values  (30001, 141, 7);
```

I'm a newbie in sql, how can i generate this sequence of inserts ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Would you mind a more efficient approach of the form, `INSERT
INTO suv_owner.gruppiruoliprocedure
  (
    ...
  )
  (SELECT .....FROM suv_owner.gruppi g ....
  )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Just take your existing query, and modify your `SELECT` to concatenate the `INSERT` statement with the `g.id` value.

FYI: `||` is Oracle's string concatenation operator.  I'm not familiar with DB2, but I believe it supports the same syntax for concatenating strings.  So the query should work for both databases (I hope).

```
select 'insert into SUV_OWNER.GRUPPIRUOLIPROCEDURE (GRUPPOID, RUOLOID, PROCEDURAID) values (' || g.id || ', 141, 7);'
from SUV_OWNER.gruppi g 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM SUV_OWNER.GRUPPIRUOLIPROCEDURE grp 
  WHERE grp.gruppoid=g.gruppoid 
  AND GRP.RUOLOID = 50)
AND G.CHIAVE LIKE 'ANA%';
```