# Script to generate SQL INSERT statements from SELECT statement in LinqPad

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

Is there any easy way to create individual SQL `INSERT` statements from each row of the results of a `SELECT` query in Linqpad, other than [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482910/2363207)?

[This](https://jonnybekkum.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/linqpad-dumpasinsert-extension/) is close to what I want but I don't think it accepts a SQL `SELECT` string as input.

[This](https://gist.github.com/praschl/30a8eeebe886812a1ffe09bfbb5aa81e) is also close to what I want but the output isn't individual `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to work in SQL in LINQPad rather than LINQ?

Comment: I'm just more familiar with SQL at this point than LINQ.

Comment: But you have a connection to your database setup in LINQPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DumpAsInsert` from your first suggestion.

Because `DumpAsInsert` uses the `IEnumerable` more than once, you have to instantiate the query into memory:

```
var sel = this.ExecuteQuery<Accounts>(@"Select * from Accounts Where Actid < 100").ToList();
sel.DumpAsInsert("Accountscopy", "Actid");
```

Comment: I copied the code from the first link into a new LINQPad tab and then edited the `Main()` section to include your lines above. This works perfectly for tables, thanks. My use case is a custom select query (I cannot create a view since I have read-only access to the db). Do you know how I could change your syntax to use a select query. I tried `var sel = this.ExecuteQueryDynamic("Select x,y,z, from tableName").ToList();` and `sel.DumpAsInsert("TableNameInOtherDb")` but this just produced `INSERT INTO [TableNameInOtherDb] () VALUES ();` Any ideas?

Comment: @BarrettNashville My sample code was exactly what I executed against MS SQL Server using a LINQPad connection to generate SQL `INSERT` statements for each record. What SQL are you trying to talk to?

Comment: Right. I was just saying that I couldn't figure out a way to leave out the `Accounts` type and just pass a custom `SELECT` query as an argument. So, let's say I wanted to generate `INSERT` statements for a statement like `SELECT Actid, AccountName + ' (ARCHIVE)' as ModifiedAccountName from Accounts` as an argument. I don't think it will work because the `DumpAsInsert` generates the field list from the table name passed as a type. But, it's not a big deal. I'll go ahead and mark it as answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BarrettNashville If you have a connection setup in LINQPad, it should have created classes for the tables automatically when you created the connection. The `DumpAsInsert` uses that class to create the `INSERT` statements. If you don't have a class or connection, why not just use straight SQL to [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)?